# I am trying to export a PDF from Word 2010 via WINE and the fonts don't embed

Tags: wine, fonts, pdf

I am trying to export a word doc as PDF in word 2010 via wine and none of the answers I have looked at provide a clear fix. The fonts don't embed and I end up with bitmap fonts. I have copied over the native fontsub and t2embed dll's from windows into drive_c/windows/system32 etc and overridden the builtin version of these dll's, is this the correct method? none of the methods/answers explain this clearly. Looking at the wine bugs this was resolved in wine several versions ago and yet the builtin dll's don't seem to work...

Any help would be gratefully appreciated as I really don't want to have a win7 VM just for word :-/

Comment: silly question, but have you tried opening the file in LibreOffice and exporting it from there?

Comment: no... but the fonts will have to be available to LibreOffice, they are currently installed in drive_c. But it's an interesting work around, I will try, but I am still looking for the solution via word 2010. Many people have got this working, but the resolution isn't clear...

Comment: Are you still having this problem? What fonts are you trying to embed? Do they embed the way you want on a native Windows installation of Word?